# cocos2dx Android Studio crash in System.loadLibrary(libName)

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I want to use cocos2dx Android Studio in mac.

I downloaded:

> android-ndk-r9d, android studio 2.1.1 and apache-ant-1.9.7. cocos2dx 3.11.1

Now I am successfully creating a project by using command:

```
cocos new TEST -p com.your_company.test -l cpp -d /Users/mac-corei5-1/Desktop/Sayem/cocos2dx/Project
```

Now when I am trying to run project in Android Studio in emulator or android device it is crashing in `System.loadLibrary(libName); where libName=MyGame`
I got this crash log in logcat

```
  06-30 04:46:15.291 4866-4866/com.your_company.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: com.your_company.test, PID: 4866
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load MyGame from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.your_company.test-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.your_company.test-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
                     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
                     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:246)
                     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:260)
                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Right now the support for Android studio is not great, there's a patch in the github repository that allow to work better in Android Studio, debug, etc. But it's not in the official cocos2d-x release version maybe for version 3.13. You should check Cocos2d-x forums. While Android Studio 2.2 is on preview version is difficult to make sure that the patch works without problem. I recommend you use Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Even thought Cocos2d-x 3.10+ has bought in android studio support and gradle build support it still very much buggy. The reasom your build crashes is because you haven't actually created the .so file by using the Android-Studio build option. Try running

```
cocos compile -p android --android-studio
```

Via a CLI so that it correctly generates the files.

Then you can run the project via Android-studio, but remember any time you change the source of your game you have to run the CLI command. Proper workaround yet to be found.